# Can’t install a specific version of VirtualBox via Homebrew: “Brew: Found a cask named ‘virtualbox@5.2.22’ instead”

Tags: macos, homebrew

I want to install a particular version of VirtualBox, namely 5.2.22, on my MacBook Pro via `brew`

This is the error message i got from

```
$ brew install virtualbox@5.2.22
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "virtualbox@5.2.22"
Found a cask named "virtualbox@5.2.22" instead.
```

So how can I install this version in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casks are installed via `brew cask install` so:

```
brew cask install virtualbox@5.2.22
```

Comment: Now it fails with: Error: Cask 'virtualbox@5.2.22' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

`cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/cask)"`

`brew log Casks/virtualbox.rb`

That will give a list of commits and you can find which one you need. Once you find the commit you need, copy it and do

`git checkout wanted_commit`

For the brew install, do

`HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew cask install virtualbox`

This will get the version from the commit you checked out.

Other option is once you get the commit, you can

`brew cask install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/wanted_commit/Casks/virtualbox.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instruction how to set a particular version of a cask package https://zeckli.github.io/en/2016/11/05/use-homebrew-cask-to-downgrad-or-install-en.html

E.g. for setting a virtual box package, I've used the next data:

- version '5.2.22,126460'
- sha256 'b54c43476ec7b95998cd45a257e3fc9838121db57f742f921fec7e895dbd8472'